# Delete MQ Series subscriptions on Windows

Tags: ibm-mq

Is there a DOS or Windows scripting command to remove all MQ Series subscriptions to a given MQ topic?  Currently we go directly to the MQ Explorer to manually remove subscriptions one by one for a given topic when testing our application.

Comment: What version of MQ do you use?  The `runmqsc` command is used as a CLI to administer MQ.  You would have to parse the output to be able to script the task you mention.  I work mostly on Linux and have an awk command that can parse the output if you have awk available I can provide this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `runmqsc` command to view and administer IBM MQ from the command prompt or a script (For example Powershell or a Batch file).

To display all subscriptions to a topic:

```
echo DIS SUB(*) WHERE(TOPICSTR EQ 'Some/Topic/String') | runmqsc QMGRNAME
```

To delete a subscription:

```
echo DELETE SUB('SUBSCRIPTION.NAME') | runmqsc QMGRNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (although withdrawn) SupportPac
[MA01 = q.exe](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24000647)
can also help you.
Works fast but the parameters are a bit tricky